# Proving the solutions to $c = a^2x^2 + b^2y^2 + 2ab xy\rho$ as $\rho$ changes where $x$ and $y$ are chosen

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the equation

$$c =  a^2x^2 + b^2y^2 + 2ab xy\rho  $$

$|a| > 0$, $|b| > 0$, and that $|\rho| \leq 1$.

If $c$ is fixed and the signs of  $x$ and $y$ are different, I want to show that as $\rho$ increases that $|x|+|y|$ must go up to retain the same value of $c$.

At first this seems trivial because in the scenario described an increase in $\rho$ causes $2abxy\rho$ to go down so it must be the case that $a^2x^2 + b^2y^2$ must increase via $x$ and/or $y$ but for  $|x|+|y|$ to increase then the change(s) in $x$ and $y$ go in the same direction they're already in which would in turn further decrease $2abxy\rho$. ($x$ and $y$ could flip signs I suppose but I don't think this would be the case)

So in other words, it's not obvious that this will always have a solution (even though there is). I think If I should that $a^2x^2 + b^2y^2$ changes more rapidly than $2ab xy\rho$ then the solution would follow but I'm not stuck.

Comment: did you try to apply the implicit function theorem?

Comment: I'm looking through the wiki, and while it looks familiar I'm not sure how to use it here (It's been a few years since I took multivariate and this may have been one of the parts I didn't commit to memory haha)

Comment: you would consider the implicit function $F(x(c), y(c), c) = 0$ and investigate $x'(c)$ and $y'(c)$

Comment: okay, I'll look into it, thank you!